# How can I fix the scope of a array variable so that I can map through it in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, scope

I have the following code:

```
const getNFTs = async (address: string) => {
... // hidden for brevity

    //Nested code
    const promises = Array.from({length: output.toNumber()}).map() => {
        ... // hidden for brevity
    }

const promiseArray = await Promise.all(promises); //returns object
const imageArray = Object.values(promiseArray); //converts to array
}
```

If I was to console.log **imageArray** I am given an array like this:

`['https://imagepath.com/image1.png','https://imagepath.com/image2.png','https://imagepath.com/image3.png',]`

I want to use **imageArray** to map through the array and render a grid of images on the UI. But when I try to map through this, I get an error that **imageArray is not defined** most likely due to scoping issues.

Do I write the map function (*with the required HTML/JSX markup*) within the **getNFTs** async function? Or is there a better way to access the array to generate the list of images on the UI?

Comment: promiseArray should already be an array, so using Object.values not needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`promiseArray` *should* already be an array of image URLs, `Object.values` will effectively yield the same value. Recall that an Array is just a special object of associative key-value pairs, i.e. the keys are the array indices and the values are the stored array values. If the returned resolved value *isn't* the image URLs then you can likely "unpack" them higher up in the Promise chain when processing the asynchronous requests.

You can save this array to the outer scope by adding some React state to hold this array value, and enqueue a state update to save it and trigger a rerender.

Example:

```
const [imageArray, setImageArray] = React.useState([]);

...

const getNFTs = async (address: string) => {
  ... // hidden for brevity

  //Nested code
  const promises = Array.from({ length: output.toNumber() }).map() => {
    ... // hidden for brevity
  }

  const imageArray = await Promise.all(promises);
  setImageArray(imageArray);
};

...
```

Later you can reference the `imageArray` state and render it as necessary.

```
imageArray.map(.....)
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention the project is also using Typescript. setImageArray(promiseArray) is throwing an error: "is not assignable to type..."

I've set the React state that holds the value to the following but with no luck:   const [imageArray, setImageArray] = useState<string[]>([])

Comment: @ImranR What is the issue/error after typing the state to be an array of strings? Would it possible to create a *running* [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo of your code we could inspect and debug live?

Comment: Argument of type '(string | undefined)[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<string[]>'.

Unfortunately, I'm not sure how much of the project I can share publicly apart from the above, although I appreciate it's difficult to debug without a working example.

Comment: @ImranR Ah, I see. You may only need to surround with a `try/catch` and handle when `imageArray` is ***not*** an array of resolved promises. Or provide any non-undefined fallback value, i.e. `setImageArray(imageArray ?? []);` or only enqueue the state update if `imageArray` is defined, i.e. `if (imageArray?.length) setImageArray(imageArray);`. Basically anything that makes it so you can assert that the `imageArray` state will ***always*** be an array (*of strings*). Does this make sense?

Comment: Yep, that made sense. Thanks again for your help :)